# How do you create a cloud of a volatile snow in Blender?

Tags: particles

I want to recreate a train from the show Snowpiercer and am struggling with how to model the snow that is thrown into the air by the wheels of the train.

In the show it looks like this:

[image: Snowpiercer-SideShot]

What I currently have is this

[image]

What I have right now are basically meta balls spawned from particle generators which are hidden inside the wheel, but it looks way less energetic than the original one.

Since the train in the show is CGI, I presumed I should be able to recreate it. How do you create this shaped cloud?

Comment: It's most likely a combination of 2D overlays in a post processing software like After Effects. It is computationally way cheaper to do it like that rather than using volumetric lighting for instance. You can emulate it with planes with alpha textures in Blender. See for instance this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7uq2_LqlMA (first find in google about the subject) Also, use depth of field to blur elements not in focus. There are smoke simulations in the show but I don't think this particular effect was simulated. My 2 cents

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely take a look. What exactly did you google btw?

Comment: you can try it with a procedural texture but I doubt it will be as good as smoke simulation, unless you accept a bit of unrealism

Comment: Look for "smoke card" or "alpha texture smoke". Nice thing is you can even use an array of images if it is animated